# How can I write a solid circle in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I want to insert solid circle in a formula in mathematics stack exchange question, which uses MathJax. how can I do that?

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFIkO.png)?

Comment: Questions about MathJax are off-topic here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, where can I post questions about MathJax?

Comment: Since you want to know this in order to use it on Math StackExchange, you can post here question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See also [this](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive) comprehensive list of symbols.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two filled circles in MathJax, both of which represent binary operators:

```
$a \bullet b = c \cdot d = e$
```

[image]

> [Live example on MathB.in](http://mathb.in/70469)